# To customize the webapp class loader for all the webapps

Tags: tomcat, classloader

How to customize the webapp class loader for all the webapps in tomcat using a common webappclassloader?

I saw that I can extend class loader and add it in the context tag for each and every webapp, is there a way to put this as common classloader for all the webapps and also where I should place this classloader .class file?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to extend the common class loader in tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the custom class loader in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`.

To replace the default loader for all webapps, a convenient solution is modifying `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Loader className="test.loader.MyWebappLoader" /><!-- add this element -->
</Context>
```

Here is a sample code:

```
package test.loader;
import org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader;
public class MyWebappLoader extends WebappLoader {
    public MyWebappLoader() {
        System.err.println("!! create MyWebappLoader !!");
    }
    public MyWebappLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
        System.err.println("!! create MyWebappLoader !!");
    }
}
```

For more detail, you can read [Tomcat document - The Loader Component](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html). It work on Tomcat 7~9.

Comment: thanks, I have one more question. is there a way to extend or customise the common class loader which loads all the common jars for all the webapps?

Comment: I don't know how to customize the common class loader. Is there any special requirement?

Comment: May i know, who does pass the parameter for constructor ? i have same context file defined, but in run time i am getting a class which is not expected to be passed.

Comment: By adding `new RuntimeException().printStackTrace();` to your constructor. The call stack will be printed, it could give you some clue.